# Spring StreamBridge Out Of Memory when processing bulk messages over stream bridge

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream, spring-gcp

I am using stream bridge to send messages over pubsub

I have some 100k messages that I need to push to pubsub. I am using executor pool of 5 threads to do the job

```
private void fetchAndPublish(List<MyObject> list) {
    int threads = 5 < list.size() ? 5 : list.size();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = list.stream()
        .map(s -> new MyRunnable(s))
        .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, es))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
    es.shutdown();
  }
  
   public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final MyObject myObject;

    public MyRunnable(MyObject myObject) {
      this.myObject = myObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
          Message<MyObject> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(myObject)
              .build();
          messagePublisherService.publish(message);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
          log.error("Failed ", exception);
        }
    }
  }
```

My service to publish message is here

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MessagePublisherService {

  @Value("${publish.destination:myDes-out-0}")
  private String destination;

  @Autowired
  private StreamBridge streamBridge;

  public void publish(Message<MyObject> message) {
    log.info("publishing {}", message.getPayload().getId());
    streamBridge.send(destination, message);
  }

}
```

It works good, but after some time I am getting Out of memory exception. What I am noticing is the memory is not release as soon as the data is pushed to streamBridge

I have 16GB of heap memory, and it gets filled very quickly. My data is not that huge.

Dynatrace Stats
I can see the initially the publish call to pubsubs took 200+ms. But progressively this time was increased and occuapaid resources

This is my Dynatrace slowly we can see that in the beginning the requests to PUBLISH to pubsub took small time

[image]

After some time it started to take so much time and occupy resources

[image]
And then occupied resources

Comment: Without a reproducible sample it will be hard to answer, especially when your code is not even showing StreamBridge. But regardless even if it did, it would be a pure speculation to say who is not releasing and what?

Comment: Probably would be great to see some memory report to determine some hints what really eats your memory.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky. I have stream bridge in example. Is there any other way to do this, than stream bridge?

Comment: @ArtemBilan. what I am seeing that when I am trying to process string of size 100kb and total items 100k. I am running this is parallel with executor threadpool. Stream bridge is not releasing threads. If I comment out stream bridge part, the code just works fine. is StreamBridge not thread safe and is it designed to work asynchronously as well.

Comment: Why do you repeat the same comment? Of course everyone here can see just one from you. I wonder if that is not a Pub/Sub problem... Any chances to test your solution with Kafka or Rabbit binders?

Comment: @ArtemBilan. Apologies. I have just access to pubsub binder. I commented out streamBridge.send code and tested, everything is fine. I do not have access to Kafka or rabbit to simulate this.

Comment: To comment out `StreamBridge` it too harsh: you eliminate not only a binder, but the whole Spring Cloud Stream. That's why I suggest to test against other binder impl to be sure where to dig more. Not sure why you don't have access to RabbitMQ since it is an easy step to download it and install locally: https://www.rabbitmq.com/. Another way is to use a Docker image.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have checked in dynatrace, that progressively the time to the publish to grpc://google.pubsub.v1.Publisher is increasing and not releasing resources.

Comment: OK. So, it is indeed a GCP ground. Please, consider to raise a GH issue to let the respective Google team to look into: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp